# extract part of json into another object and keep link between both

Tags: javascript, json

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "date": "2013-03-07",
         "id": "2",
         "vt_color": "#548dd4",
         "vt_name": "follow up",
         "duration": "20",
         "time_booked": "12:00:00",
         "stats": "booked",
         "doctor_id": "00002",
         "patient_id": "00003"
      },
      {
         "date": "2013-03-08",
         "id": "3",
         "vt_color": "#76923c",
         "vt_name": "ultrasound",
         "duration": "30",
         "time_booked": "08:00:00",
         "stats": "booked",
         "pt_name": "demo patien",
         "dr_name": "Momen Alzalabany",
         "doctor_id": "00002",
         "patient_id": "00009"
      }
   ] 
}
```

what i want is to create another array out of this including vt_name,vt_color and index of data
so i use jquery

```
var words = [];

$.each(arr['data'],function(ref){
    words[this.doctor_id].push({name: this.vt_color,color: this.vt_name,index:ref});
});
console.log(koko);
```

FAIL : words[this.do_id] is not defined....

how can i do this ? i want outcome to be

sorry i'm a newbie with json/js

i want outcome in php would be

```
['00002'=>[
            ['name'=>'follow up','color'=>'#548dd4',index=>[0,3,4]],
            ['name'=>'ultrasound','color'=>'#769dd4',index=>[1,5,8]]
          ]
 ]
```

Comment: where is you array? is it a php array/object? it's impossible to answer your question. improve your question (and possibly provide a jsfiddle ) of working example

Comment: is the **this.do_id** in `FAIL : words[this.do_id] ..` a typo or maybe the "bug"? and what does `console.log(koko)` mean in this context?! and how can `index` be an Array, if it is only one key ?! Please provide more Context, Information ... Thx

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the type of words to object (not array), since you want a map with a string (e.g. '00002') as key:

   ```
   var words = {};
   ```
2. You want do add to an array which does not exist. You need to create it first:

   ```
   words[this.doctor_id] = words[this.doctor_id] || []; // creates an array if not already existing
   words[this.doctor_id].push({name: this.vt_color,color: this.vt_name,index:ref});
   ```

Comment: If this is the answer of the question you deserve at least +1 for understanding it, although the part of the result `... index=>[0,3,4] `  is missing.(i will wait to awared my +1)